# z-index on absolute having no effect

Tags: html, css, z-index

I am trying to obtain a folding paper effect .

I made 2 faces to the page.

On click(active) I want the back slices of the paper  to be seen after folding.

THE PROBLEM is that the Front face of the page seams to haves Z-index bigger so when it fold only a small part of back face is seen.

I need back slices b1 and b2 to have indexes bigger than f2 f3 when active (with a transition delay to seam natural).

Here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Double Gate Fold</title>
    <script>

        var front = new Image();
        front.src = 'Flyer2pag1.png';

        function scaleSize(maxW, maxH, currW, currH){

            var ratio = currH / currW;

            if(currW >= maxW && ratio <= 1){
                currW = maxW;
                currH = currW * ratio;
            } else if(currH >= maxH && ratio>1){
                currH = maxH;
                currW = currH / ratio;
            }

            return [currW, currH];
        }


        front.onload = function () {

            var frontWidth = this.width;
            var frontHeight = this.height;
            var newSize = scaleSize(1000, 1000, frontWidth, frontHeight);
            frontWidth = newSize[0];
            frontHeight = newSize[1];


            var Dim_View = document.querySelectorAll(".view");
            for (var i = 0; i < Dim_View.length; i++) {
                Dim_View[i].style.width = frontWidth + "px";
                Dim_View[i].style.height = frontHeight + "px";
            }

            var Dim_Slice = document.querySelectorAll(".slice");
            for (var i = 0; i < Dim_Slice.length; i++) {
                Dim_Slice[i].style.width = frontWidth / 4 + "px";

            }
            var Poz_f1 = document.querySelectorAll(".f1");
            for (var i = 0; i < Poz_f1.length; i++) {
                Poz_f1[i].style.backgroundPositionX = '0px';
                Poz_f1[i].style.backgroundPositionY = '0px';
            }
            var Poz_f2 = document.querySelectorAll(".f2");
            for (var i = 0; i < Poz_f2.length; i++) {
                Poz_f2[i].style.backgroundPositionX = +frontWidth * 0.75 + "px";
                Poz_f2[i].style.backgroundPositionY = '0px';
            }

            var Poz_f3 = document.querySelectorAll(".f3");
            for (var i = 0; i < Poz_f3.length; i++) {
                Poz_f3[i].style.backgroundPositionX = +frontWidth * 0.5 + "px";
                Poz_f3[i].style.backgroundPositionY = '0px';
            }
            var Poz_f4 = document.querySelectorAll(".f4");
            for (var i = 0; i < Poz_f4.length; i++) {
                Poz_f4[i].style.backgroundPositionX = +frontWidth * 0.25 + "px";
                Poz_f4[i].style.backgroundPositionY = '0px';
            }
        }

        var back = new Image();
        back.src = 'Flyer2pag2.png';



        back.onload = function () {

           
            var backWidth = this.width;
            var backHeight = this.height;
            var newSize = scaleSize(1000, 1000, backWidth, backHeight);
            backWidth = newSize[0];
            backHeight = newSize[1];


            var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
   
            canvas.width = backWidth;
            canvas.height = backHeight;

            context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
            context.scale(-1, 1);

            context.drawImage(back, -back.width / 2, -back.height / 2);

            context.restore();
            context.save();

            setTimeout(function () {
                var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
                console.log(dataURL);


                var Poz_b1 = document.querySelectorAll(".b1");
                for (var i = 0; i < Poz_b1.length; i++) {
                    Poz_b1[i].style.backgroundPositionX = '0px';
                    Poz_b1[i].style.backgroundPositionY = '0px';
                    Poz_b1[i].style.backgroundImage = "url('" + dataURL + "')";

                }
                var Poz_b2 = document.querySelectorAll(".b2");
                for (var i = 0; i < Poz_b2.length; i++) {
                    Poz_b2[i].style.backgroundPositionX = +backWidth * 0.75 + "px";
                    Poz_b2[i].style.backgroundPositionY = '0px';
                    Poz_b2[i].style.backgroundImage = "url('" + dataURL + "')";
                }

                var Poz_b3 = document.querySelectorAll(".b3");
                for (var i = 0; i < Poz_b3.length; i++) {
                    Poz_b3[i].style.backgroundPositionX = +backWidth * 0.5 + "px";
                    Poz_b3[i].style.backgroundPositionY = '0px';
                    Poz_b3[i].style.backgroundImage = "url('" + dataURL + "')";
                }
                var Poz_b4 = document.querySelectorAll(".b4");
                for (var i = 0; i < Poz_b3.length; i++) {
                    Poz_b4[i].style.backgroundPositionX = +backWidth * 0.25 + "px";
                    Poz_b4[i].style.backgroundPositionY = '0px';
                    Poz_b4[i].style.backgroundImage = "url('" + dataURL + "')";
                }


            }, 100);





        }
    </script>



    <style>
        .view {
            position:absolute;
            margin-left: 300px;
            -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
            -moz-perspective: 1000px;
            -ms-perspective: 1000px;
            perspective: 1000px;
        }
        
        .slice {
            position:absolute;
            background: #ffffff;
            height: 100%;
            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
            -moz-transform-origin: left center;
            -o-transform-origin: left center;
            -ms-transform-origin: left center;
            transform-origin: left center;
            -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: -o-transform 1s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: -ms-transform 1s ease-in-out;
            transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
            -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
        }

        .view f1, .view .f2, .view .f3, .view .f4 {
            
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
            -moz-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
            -o-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
            -ms-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
            transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
        }

        .view .b2, .view .b3, .view .b4 {
          
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
            -moz-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
            -o-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
            -ms-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
            transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
        }

        .b1, .b2, .b3, .b4 {
            -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
            -o-backface-visibility: visible;
            -ms-backface-visibility: visible;
            backface-visibility: visible;
        }
       

        /*********************************************
        Folding Front
        *********************************************/


        .RF:active .f1 {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,150deg);
            -moz-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,150deg);
            -o-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,150deg);
            -ms-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,150deg);
            transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,150deg);
        }

        .RF:active .f2 {
            z-index:-5;
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-110deg);
            -moz-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-110deg);
            -o-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-110deg);
            -ms-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-110deg);
            transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-110deg);
        }

        .RF:active .f3 {
            z-index:-5;
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-50deg);
            -ms-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-50deg);
            -o-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-50deg);
            -moz-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-50deg);
            transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-50deg);
        }

        .RF:active .f4 {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-120deg);
            -moz-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-120deg);
            -ms-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-120deg);
            -o-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-120deg);
            transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-120deg);
        }
       
            .RF:active .b1 {

            -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,150deg);
            -moz-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,150deg);
            -o-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,150deg);
            -ms-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,150deg);
            transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,150deg);
            z-index:5000;
        }

        .RF:active .b2 {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-110deg);
            -moz-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-110deg);
            -o-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-110deg);
            -ms-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-110deg);
            transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-110deg);
        }

        .RF:active .b3 {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-50deg);
            -ms-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-50deg);
            -o-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-50deg);
            -moz-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-50deg);
            transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-50deg);
        }
      

        .RF:active .b4 {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-120deg);
            -moz-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-120deg);
            -ms-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-120deg);
            -o-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-120deg);
            transform: translate3d(100%,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-120deg);
            z-index: 5000;
             
        }
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="RB">
        <!--<img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/huge-basic-icons-part-3/512/Rotate_3d.png " />-->
        <p>RB</p>

        <div class="RF">
            <!--<img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/huge-basic-icons-part-3/512/Rotate_3d.png" />-->

            <p>RF</p>

            <div class="view">
                <div class=" slice b1" style="background-size: cover;">
                    <div class="slice b2" style="background-size: cover;">
                        <div class="slice b3" style="background-size: cover;">
                            <div class="slice b4" style="background-size: cover;">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="view">
                <div class=" slice f1" style="background-image: url(Flyer2pag1.png); background-size: cover;">
                    <div class="slice f2 " style="background-image: url(Flyer2pag1.png); background-size: cover;">
                        <div class="slice f3 " style="background-image: url(Flyer2pag1.png); background-size: cover; ">
                            <div class="slice f4 " style="background-image: url(Flyer2pag1.png); background-size: cover; ">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            

        </div>
    </div>

    
   
    <canvas id="myCanvas" style="background:#0094ff;display:none;"></canvas>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't see your code, is the link broken?

Comment: new link http://codebeautify.org/alleditor/b5b05c

Comment: It's the same link? But it's still not working... :/

Comment: my problem is that i can't effect z-index in child div that are in 2 separate groups

Comment: After looking at the code in the link, where are you applying the z-index (is it in the js blob?). The z-index is going to be set to the context of whatever the parent element is (that has a position). In this case is ".veiw" has a position, you're going to need to control this by acting upon the parents z-index, assuming they're siblings in the same position context container.

Comment: i added it to the question

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle / demo to show us what youre talking about? and post your code inside the question so things like broken links wont render the question unhelpful to other people

Comment: Try using http://jsfiddle.net/ (Edit: What ^he^ said)

Comment: In your code, why are you loading images in javascript instead of just having them in your page so they load automatically?

Comment: ryan rossiter in need it to solve a problem whit the back of the paper page that i am simulating (it's a must)

Comment: I have this problem

group A   { child a1  child a2  child a3  child a4  

group B   { child b1  child b2  child b3  child b4  

i what   b1 and b2 to have z-index bigger than a2 and a3 after lets say active(Holding click pushed)

keep in mind that group A and B have position absolute

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand the problem is that the z-indexs are not working the way you'd expect them to work. I suspect this is because you're controlling the z-index per child. i.e. children of 'f' have a higher index than children of 'b' but the children in 'f' are still behind or not overlaying the 'b' container.

this is because at that level you're going to need to apply the z-index to the parent containers while flipping through the pages. Here's an example that can maybe explain a little better than my ramblings:

#### the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bfbddn70/

#### html:

```
<div id="top-parent">
  <div class="pages b">
    <div class="b1">
       content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pages f">
    <div class="f1">
        content
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
#top-parent {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background: grey;
}

.pages {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.pages.b {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.pages.f {    
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.b1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #eee;      
}

/**
 * notice that the nested elements don't interact with each other 
 * the grey page is still above the white page even though the white 
 * page has a higher z-index. This is because at the level in which they are
 * visually interacting, the parent container `.pages.b` is has a higher z-index
 * than the parent container `.pages.f`
*/
.f1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;      
}
```

Comment: My problem is group A { child a1 child a2 child a3 child a4     group B { child b1 child b2 child b3 child b4     i want b1 and b2 to have z-index bigger than a2 and a3 after lets say active(Holding click pushed) keep in mind that group A and B have position absolute

Comment: if you want the children in a and b to have that kind of interactivity they need to be in the same position context.